# Necesito relacionar dos tablas, que el valor de una columna en tabla A sea tomado en otra columna en tabla B

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo una tabla que es productos, y otra tabla que es tipoProductos, la estructura de la primera es basica: id, codigo, descripcion, tipoProducto, la tabla tipoProductos solo lleva id y descripcion, asi que necesito que la tabla productos, en el campo tipo, vea los registros almacenados en la tabla tipos.

Alguna sugerencia, he estado leyendo acerca de la 3FN de bases de datos sin embargo soy aun novato y estoy aprendiedo en el camino.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes dos tablas que son las siguientes:

productos

- id
- nombre
- codigo
- descripcion
- id_tipo_producto

tipo_producto

- id
- nombre
- descripcion

ya tu tienes relacionada las dos tablas de manera que al ejecutar una consulta podria ser de la siguiente forma

```
SELECT p.id AS Id, p.name AS NombreProducto, t.nombre AS tipoProducto  FROM productos p
INNER JOIN tipo_producto t ON p.id_tipo_producto = t.id
```

de esta forma la consulta anterior te arrojara todos los productos junto a que tipo de producto es.

```
// tabla de tipo de producto
CREATE TABLE `tipo_producto` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `descripcion` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));


// tabla de productos
CREATE TABLE `productos` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `descripcion` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `id_tipo_producto` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `id_tipo_producto_idx` (`id_tipo_producto` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `id_tipo_producto`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_tipo_producto`)
    REFERENCES `tipo_producto` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

Comment: Me has dado una idea, con el uso de los indexes. Gracias.

Comment: He publicado una respuesta, revisala y si hay algun comentario pues te agradezco. Saludos @Lucho T.

Answer (score 1):

Relaciona con una [llave foránea](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clave_for%C3%A1nea) la columna *tipoProducto* de la tabla *Productos* que apunte a la columna *id* de *TipoProductos*, de ésta manera cuando veas el *tipoProducto* de *Productos* sabrás que tipo de producto es fácilmente.
En un diagrama (o algo parecido) se vería así:

**Productos:**

```
Id Codigo  Descripcion                 TipoProducto
1  ABC123  Tennis Jordan blablabla...  1
2  DBA567  Vestido Louis Vuitton...    2
3  DAN082  Macbook Pro 15' retina...   2
```

**TipoProductos**

```
Id Descripcion
1  Moda y Accesorios
2  Computación
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Me sirve la informacion, sin embargo, es un pequeño sistema de inventario, donde se llevan muchos tipos de mercancia y se trata de crear los tipos, de tal manera que:

Producto: Jugo de Naranja 
Tipo Producto: Jugos

Answer (score 0):

Para relacionar dos columnas de dos tablas distintas, en primer lugar se debe definir quien es parte de quien (hijo-padre) por ejemplo:

Si tenemos bebidas y debemos especificar el tipo, sabemos entonces que bebidas tiene tipos, serian dos tablas, una de bebidas y una de tipos, ejemplo:

- Bebida: Jugo de Naranja ---------------- Tipo: Jugos
- Bebida: Cocktail de Frutas ------------- Tipo: Cocktail

Luego procedemos a crear dos indexes de tipo unique en cada una de las tablas, tanto en la tabla hijo como en la tabla padre, y apuntaran a la columna que se quieren relacionar.

Finalmente se crea una llave foranea en la tabla hijo que haga referencia a la columna de la tabla padre de donde se necesita adquirir la informacion.

Asi ha quedado mi query:

```
//Tabla tipoproductos
CREATE TABLE `tipoproductos` 
(
`idTipo` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`descripcionTipo` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
//Llaves o indexes
 PRIMARY KEY (`idTipo`),
 UNIQUE KEY `tipoProd_idx` (`descripcionTipo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `productos` 
(
`idProducto` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`codProducto` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`descripcionProducto` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`tipoProducto` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`existenciaProducto` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`costoProducto` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`precioProducto` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,

//Llaves o indexes
PRIMARY KEY (`idProducto`),
UNIQUE KEY `tipoProd_idx` (`tipoProducto`),

//Aqui la tabla hijo se relaciona
CONSTRAINT `tipoProd_FK`
FOREIGN KEY (`tipoProducto`)

REFERENCES `tipoproductos` (`descripcionTipo`) 
 ON DELETE NO ACTION
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Gracias por tus indicaciones [@Lucho T.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/12619/lucho-t) me mostraste el camino para dar con la respuesta correcta.

Comment: Deberías marcar como solución la respuesta de @LuchoT ya que actualmente tu pregunta aparece como sin solución.